# Is it possible to select texts with mouse in the case of horizontally allocated QTextEdit?

Tags: mouseevent, qgraphicsview, qtextedit, pyside6

There are three QGraphicsView in one line. If these QGraphicsView is vertically located (orientation is 0), to select texts with mouse is no problem. But if these QGrahpicsView is horizontally located, goes bad.Even if horizontally located, I must select texts vertically.

It seems that the mouse point at the time of mouse press event is decided by QTextEdit coordinate at first.
At the time of mouse move event, the mouse point is decided by the position of mouse press event as the anchor.
So is the time of mouse release event.

Is there way to select texts with mouse naturally? Or does Qt allow us to select texts with mouse vertically only?

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QTextEdit
from PySide6.QtGui import QTextDocument, QPageSize, QPainter, QBrush, QTextCharFormat, QTextOption
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, Signal, QRect, QRectF, QEvent, QSize, QSizeF, QPointF



class MainGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainGraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)


        self._mainscene = MainGraphicsScene(1)
        self._mainscene._mainview = self
        self.setScene(self._mainscene)          

class MainGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):  

    def __init__(self, orientation = 1, parent=None):

        super(MainGraphicsScene, self).__init__(parent)
        
        if orientation == 0:

            self.rootView = TextGraphicsView()        
            self.rootView.main_scene = self
            self.root_proxywidget = self.addWidget(self.rootView)
            self.rootView.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)

            self.secondaryView = SecondaryTextGraphicsView(2, self.rootView.scene())
            self.secondaryView.setSceneRect(0, self.document()._pageHeight, self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)
            self.secondary_proxywidget = self.addWidget(self.secondaryView)
            self.secondary_proxywidget.setPos(0, self.document()._pageHeight)

            self.thirdView = SecondaryTextGraphicsView(3, self.rootView.scene())
            self.thirdView.setSceneRect(0, self.document()._pageHeight*2, self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)
            self.third_proxywidget = self.addWidget(self.thirdView)
            self.third_proxywidget.setPos(0, self.document()._pageHeight*2)

            
        if orientation == 1:
            
            self.rootView = TextGraphicsView()        
            self.rootView.main_scene = self
            self.root_proxywidget = self.addWidget(self.rootView)
            self.rootView.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)

            self.secondaryView = SecondaryTextGraphicsView(2, self.rootView.scene())
            self.secondaryView.setSceneRect(0, self.document()._pageHeight, self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)
            self.secondary_proxywidget = self.addWidget(self.secondaryView)
            self.secondary_proxywidget.setPos(self.document()._pageWidth, 0)

            self.thirdView = SecondaryTextGraphicsView(3, self.rootView.scene())
            self.thirdView.setSceneRect(0, self.document()._pageHeight*2, self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)
            self.third_proxywidget = self.addWidget(self.thirdView)
            self.third_proxywidget.setPos(self.document()._pageWidth*2, 0)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.gray))      
   
    def view(self):

        return self._mainview

    def textedit(self):

        return self.document().parent()

    def document(self):

        return self.rootView.document()
    
    
class TextGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent)

        self.page = 1

        self.initScene()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        SecondaryTextGraphicsView.selectedPage = self.page
        return QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def initScene(self):
        
        self.common_scene = TextGraphicsScene()
        self.common_scene.root_view = self
        
        self.setScene(self.common_scene)
        self.setSceneRect(0, self.document()._pageHeight*(self.page -1), self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)
        self.resize(int(self.document()._pageWidth), int(self.document()._pageHeight))

        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def view(self):

        return self.main_scene._mainview
    
    def textedit(self):

        return self.common_scene.textedit
    
    def document(self):

        return self.common_scene.textedit.document()       

class SecondaryTextGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, page, scene, parent=None):

        super().__init__(scene, parent)

        self.page = page

        self.initScene()

        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)    

    def initScene(self):
        
        self.setSceneRect(0, self.document()._pageHeight*(self.page-1), self.document()._pageWidth, self.document()._pageHeight)
        self.resize(int(self.document()._pageWidth), int(self.document()._pageHeight))

    def view(self):

        return self.scene().root_view.view()

    def textedit(self):

        return self.scene().textedit()
    

    def document(self):

        return self.scene().textedit.document()


class TextGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent)        

        self.textedit = TextEdit(scene=self)        
       
        self.addWidget(self.textedit)


    def view(self):

        return self.root_view

    def document(self):

        return self.textedit.document()     
    

class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    
    def __init__(self,  scene, parent=None):

        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_InputMethodEnabled, True)
        self.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)       
      
        self.scene = scene
        self.setDocument(TextDocument(parent=self))

        self.setWordWrapMode(QTextOption.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere)
        self.setLineWrapMode(self.LineWrapMode.FixedPixelWidth)
        self.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(self.document()._pageWidth)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_InputMethodEnabled, True)
        self.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.resize(self.document()._pageSize.toSize().width(), self.document()._pageSize.toSize().height()*3)
        self.setPlainText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        \Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):


        print(event.position())
        return QTextEdit.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    
    def view(self):

        return self.scene.root_view
    
    def pageSize(self):

        return self.document()._pageSize    
        

class TextDocument(QTextDocument):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._pageSize = QPageSize.size(QPageSize.A4, QPageSize.Point)       
 
        self._pageHeight = self._pageSize.height()
        self._pageWidth  = self._pageSize.width()
        self.setDocumentMargin(30.5) 


def main():
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication([]) if QApplication.instance() is None else QApplication.instance()
    m = MainGraphicsView()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you adding a *further* QGraphicsView for each QTextEdit, while you could just add a QTextEdit? Your concept (and resulting code) seems quite convoluted, can you explain what you're trying to achieve and what is your final purpose?

Comment: @musicamante if I use QGraphicsView and shows the each page, I don't have to calculate the position of QTextLines when the document is horizontally layouted. QGraphicsView  can show each page horizontally, but in actual QTextEdit is all vertically layouted. That is why it is very simple.

Comment: That doesn't clarify *at all* why you're creating other QGraphicsViews *inside* the main scene, and doing that has absolutely nothing to do with the text layout. Just add each QTextEdit to the main scene, but be aware that if you're doing all that because you want to display a document across multiple "pages", that is certainly not a good solution (especially if you want to allow editing). Besides, it's not clear what you mean by "goes bad". I tested your code with PyQt6 (but the behavior wouldn't change with PySide6) and I found no issues in selecting text.

Comment: @musicamante I want to select texts from 1 page to 2 page (3 page) with mouse horizontally dragged. If I move mouse from the top of 1 page to the top of 2 page , the texts of 1 page is all selected. But now, I must drag until the bottom of the page. That doesn't me allow to select 2 page texts at all.

Comment: That selection is invalid anyway: the fact that you can't "select" when "pages" are laid out horizontally is actually irrelevant: they are completely different widgets, you can only see an *apparent* selection just due to the orientation, but that selection is actually wrong anyway. The approach is *wrong* by nature. QTextEdit doesn't provide such feature, and trying to "hack" your way by using convoluted (and, as said, unnecessary) ways won't solve your issue in any way, *no matter what*. Sorry, but, while not impossible, what you want to do is *very* difficult, and you cannot do it like this

Comment: Text selection in an edit widget **always** uses the x and y coordinates *relative* to that widget. If you "drag" the mouse *above* the start of the selection, the selection will **still** be relative to that widget, so it will go *above* the selection start. And using another widget (or, even worse, another QGraphicsView that embeds that widget in its scene through a graphics proxy), won't change absolutely *anything*: the mouse movement will still be relative to the initial widget mouse event. If you want to achieve a "paginated" view, you have to create a custom text widget and, most ->

Comment: -> importantly, a *completely custom* [QAbstractTextDocumentLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttextdocumentlayout.html), which is a *really* difficult task, because the default text document layout is completely private and doesn't provide any public API except from what the abstract class provides. QTextEdit is ***not*** intended for that, and (at least, at this moment, Qt6 including) doesn't provide absolutely *any* solution that allows that. This is not a bug, it's by design, and for *very good reasons*: that's not the purpose of QTextEdit, which is a text editor, not a word processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your comment:

> if I use QGraphicsView and shows the each page, I don't have to calculate the position of QTextLines when the document is horizontally layouted. QGraphicsView can show each page horizontally, but in actual QTextEdit is all vertically layouted. That is why it is very simple.

You need not to draw the lines on the basis of `QTextLayout`.

`QTextLine` also has draw method.

Please use `QTextLine` instead of `QTextLayout`.

[QTextLine draw](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtGui/QTextLine.html?highlight=qtextline#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QTextLine.draw)